# Дуплекс в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Командой

> sudo ethtool -s eth0 duplex full speed 100 autoneg off

Ставлю полный дуплекс и отключаю автоностройки сетевой. И все нормально работает.После перезагрузки компьютера Дуплекс проставляется HALF

Что сделать чтоб он все атки сохранял настройки?

Answer (score 1):

В настройках сетевого интерфейса `/etc/network/interfaces`, например для `eth0`, нужно добавить:

```
auto eth0
pre-up /usr/sbin/ethtool -s eth0 duplex full speed 100 autoneg off
```

Answer (score 0):

В качестве паллиативного решения можно эту команду (только без sudo) в скрипт автозапуска засунуть. Подробности здесь: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/создание_скрипта_автозапуска

Обратите там внимание на раздел "Выполнение скрипта при включении/отключении сети".

А насчёт постоянного сохранения настроек - это сложнее. Очень может быть, что у этой сетевой карты нет EEPROM. Тогда это в принципе невозможно.